# Вызвать выбранный пункт в инпут и заменить текст спана при выборе пункта!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="x-order-form-row">
    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ оплаты:</div>
    <div class="x-order-form-row__field x-order-form-row__field_pos_relative"><div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="payment_option">
        <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe">Выберите способ оплаты</span></span>
        <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="payment_option" name="payment_option" value="">

        <ul class="x-drop-down__list  js-dropdown">
            <li id="beznal" class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/privatbank.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Безналичный расчет</span>
            </li>
            <li id="nal" class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Наложенный платеж</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                    $(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
});
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0) {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
        }
    });
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function(){
            $('#payment_option').val($(this).html());
     });

});     
            </script>
```

Здравствуйте всем!
хотим сделать так что бы при выборе выпадающего пункта изменялс начальный span Выберите способ оплаты на выбранный! Пытался сделать через outerHTML но получается только один пункт туда загнать.. может как то через id сделать .. морочусь целый день! Помогите пожалуйста!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поправил

```js
$(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
  $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
});

$('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function(){
    $('#payment_option').val($(this).children().text());
    $('#tupe').html($(this).children().html());
});
```

```css
.js-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
.x-drop-down__list_active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-order-form-row">
    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ оплаты:</div>
    <div class="x-order-form-row__field x-order-form-row__field_pos_relative"><div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="payment_option">
        <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe">Выберите способ оплаты</span></span>
        <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="payment_option" name="payment_option" value="">

        <ul class="x-drop-down__list  js-dropdown">
            <li id="beznal" class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/privatbank.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Безналичный расчет</span>
            </li>
            <li id="nal" class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Наложенный платеж</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сейчас проверим на деле и отпишусь!)

Comment: Все работает, огромное спасибо!!! Только без img , один текст туда заносит. А как сделать так что бы вместе с img ?

Comment: Ждемсс, хотим что бы img заходил в поле с текстом )

Comment: Уже поправил, посмотрите

Comment: Капец, вчера целый день потратил!! А вы за пару минут все это сделали .. Спасибо громное !)) С полем для оплаты решили и тему ЗАКРЫЛИ! Было бы хорошо в дальнейшем получать от Вас консультации, но не знаю как связаться)

Comment: Моя почта brykin.ilia@gmail.com